# Can't align text to image

Tags: android, android-layout

This is a theme I was making for an app called EvolveSMS. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the body text to be centered in the block, and horizontally centered with the contact photo. It either appears on the top or bottom of the photos. I've attached my code and a photo of it's current state.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/holder"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/background"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:minHeight="52dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myPicture"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"
            android:maxWidth="48dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:minWidth="48dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/contactPicture"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"
            android:maxWidth="48dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorReceived"/>

        <TextView
               android:id="@+id/name"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:paddingRight="5dp"
               android:textSize="12sp"
               android:ellipsize="marquee"
               android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
               android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
               android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"
               android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
               android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>

        <ImageView
               android:layout_width="200dp"
               android:layout_height="200dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:id="@+id/media"
               android:padding="10dp"
               android:visibility="gone"
               android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <View   android:id="@+id/gifView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:alignParentLeft="true" >
    <!-- other -->
  </ImageView>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:toRightOf="@+id/image" >
    <!-- other -->
  </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to use relative or another linearlayout inside.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ImageView>
   <TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @harpun @nr4bt I'm not quite sure I understand that second block of code. Would I need to add a new relativeLayout for each picture? `@+id/contactPicture` and `@+id/myPicture`?

Comment: To align image and text that you want to center, you can use linearlayout with horizontal orientation, or you can use RelativeLayout and tell each widget to such as ImageView is at the left, Name text is right of the ImageView, Date is below Name text and its bottom is aligned to ImageView's bottom align etc

Comment: But where do the new layouts go? Between where? I'm trying this and it's even more messed up, lol.

Comment: Try to use RelativeLayout in another layout to see how it works, try to use toLeft, alignParentLeft, above, below features to understand how it really works.   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: So, you're saying I should _replace_ the LinearLayouts I have with RelativeLayouts? I thought you were saying, in addition to the code I have, add a RelativeLayout and adjust things. You want me to replace, not add. Correct?